# Error at copy command in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

my command is

```
\copy meta.amz_payment1("Date", settlement_id, type, order_id, sku, 

description, quantity, marketplace, fulfillment, order_city, order_state, 

order_postal, product_sales, shipping_credits, promotional_rebates, 

sales_tax_collected, selling_fees, fba_fees, other_transaction_fees,other, total) 

from '/Users/manish/Downloads/amz.csv' delimiter ',' csv header
```

but it gives following error :

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "-8,791.41" CONTEXT: 
>   COPY amz_payment1, line 23, column total: "-8,791.41"

Answer (score 1):

The column "total" is of type `numeric`, but the CSV file has a formatted string for that position. You should add a `varchar` column to your `meta.amz_payment1` table and copy the information into that column. After you copied in the data, you can populate the "total" column with an `UPDATE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE meta.amz_payment1 ADD COLUMN total_fmt varchar;

\copy meta.amz_payment1("Date", ... total_fmt) from ...;

UPDATE meta.amz_payment1 SET total = total_fmt::numeric;
```

then

```
ALTER TABLE meta.amz_payment1 DROP COLUMN total_fmt;
```

Comment: total_ft does not exist while trying to run

Comment: First add that column to your table, see updated answer

Comment: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "-8,791.41"
SQL state: 22P02  while trying to run update command after add column

Comment: Have you changed the `\copy` command to use the new column with `varchar` data type instead of "total"?

Comment: `total_fmt::numeric` will fail with the same error as the original `\copy`. The problem is that the `text`->`numeric` cast doesn't allow commas in the input. Postgres provides [`to_char()` and `to_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) to deal with locale-dependent numeric formatting. Though for a one-off import, I'd just strip the commas with `replace()`.